# Value of $\gamma(0)$ if $\gamma(t)=e^{2\pi it\sin(1/t)}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let's take a look at problem 18 on chapter 6 in PMA Rudin.

Let $\gamma(t)$ be curve in the complex plne, defined $[0,2\pi]$ by $$\gamma(t)=e^{2\pi it\sin \frac{1}{t}}.$$

It's defined on half-interval $(0,2\pi]$. But $\gamma(0)$ is undefined.

What about this moment ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ClementC, How Rudin defined $\gamma(0)$?

Comment: By continuity, I'd go for $e^0=1$, since $t\sin\frac{1}{t} \to 0$. (By sandwiching: $\sin$ is bounded, and $t\to0$)

Comment: @ClementC., Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend $t \mapsto t \sin(\frac{1}{t})$ on $0$ by continuity as it has finite limit (equal to $0$).